# Gatsby throws compatible issues with new version 4.x but it is working well in 2.x?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, gatsby, gatsby-remark-image

i tried to run "gatsby develop" in my application it throws following compatible issues,

My node version is 16.17.0 and gatsby is 4.24.1. i can guess that it says to upgrade those depdencies to latest version, am unable to identify which version i need to use for gatsby 4.24.1?

Anyone guide me the right solution for this to know the compatible version and solve the below error?

```
  warn Plugin gatsby-transformer-remark is not compatible with your gatsby version
     4.24.1 - It requires gatsby@^2.0.33
    warn Plugin gatsby-plugin-remove-generator is not compatible with your gatsby
    version 4.24.1 - It requires gatsby@2.x.x
    warn Plugin gatsby-transformer-remark is not compatible with your gatsby version
     4.24.1 - It requires gatsby@^2.0.33
    warn Plugin gatsby-plugin-remove-generator is not compatible with your gatsby
    version 4.24.1 - It requires gatsby@2.x.x
    ERROR
    
    Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'styleAttributes')
    
    
    
      TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'styleAttributes')
    
      - index.js:22 applyOptions
        [Project]/[gatsby-remark-image-attributes]/dist/index.js:22:3
    
      - index.js:105 module.exports
        [Project]/[gatsby-remark-image-attributes]/dist/index.js:105:3
    
      - extend-node-type.js:247
        [Project]/[gatsby-transformer-remark]/extend-node-type.js:247:30
    
      - util.js:16 tryCatcher
        [Project]/[bluebird]/js/release/util.js:16:23
    
      - reduce.js:166 Object.gotValue
        [Project]/[bluebird]/js/release/reduce.js:166:18
    
      - reduce.js:155 Object.gotAccum
        [Project]/[bluebird]/js/release/reduce.js:155:25
    
      - util.js:16 Object.tryCatcher
        [Project]/[bluebird]/js/release/util.js:16:23
    
      - promise.js:547 Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler
        [Project]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:547:31
    
      - promise.js:604 Promise._settlePromise
        [Project]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:604:18
    
      - promise.js:649 Promise._settlePromise0
        [Project]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:649:10
    
      - promise.js:729 Promise._settlePromises
        [Project]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:729:18
    
      - async.js:93 _drainQueueStep
        [Project]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:93:12
    
      - async.js:86 _drainQueue
        [Project]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:86:9
    
      - async.js:102 Async._drainQueues
        [Project]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:102:5
    
      - async.js:15 Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate]
        [Project]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:15:14
    
      - timers:466 processImmediate
        node:internal/timers:466:21
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "error" prompted is a warning, hence it doesn't break the compilation, despite needs to be approached. I'd say (and it seems) that the plugins are not well upgraded, although Gatsby is on `v4.24.1`: confirm that in your `package-lock.json` (or `yarn.lock`) and upgraded it accordingly.

If you are using yarn I'd recommend using [`yarn upgrade-interactive`](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/upgrade-interactive/) to know what versions are deprecated and could be upgraded to what version.

As you pointed, the underlying error:

> ```
> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'styleAttributes')
> ```

Can be related to `gatsby-transformer-remark` plugin version or to a breaking change of the upgrading process that needs to be tweaked, without further details and knowledge of what's `styleAttributes` and of your structure it's hard to say.

You can see in the npm docs that the [`gatsby-transformer-remark`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-transformer-remark) latest version is the `5.24`.